# Asymptotic Notations Iterative Method for Solving Recurrences

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Recurrence T(n)= T(n^1\2) + O(lg(lg(n)))

The solution suggests substituting

m = lg(n)

So the recurrence becomes

S(m)= S(m\2) + O(lg(lg(m)))

Then solving using iterative method for solvng recurrences.

How did the substitution above of m= lg(n) produce S(m)? In other words, why did it succeed in getting rid of n^1\2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.